Computing an alternate sign infinite series with residue theorem
Solve the sum $$ s(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{\sin{kx}}{k} $$ with $x\in \mathbb{R}$. I saw that the sum $$ \tilde{s}(x) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1} (-1)^k \frac{\sin{kx}}{k} = s(x)$$ So I have $$ 2\cdot s(x)=\sum_{k\neq 0} (-1)^k \frac{\sin{kx}}{k} $$ But I don't know how to include the value $k=0$ so that I can apply the theorem, I assume that I need to add some value $\epsilon$  so that then I can expand and make it disappear, but I don't know where to start. I would really appreciate some help.
Thank you to everyone that helped, here's what I came up with. I used the fact that given $z_k$ the poles of a function $f(z)$ such as $|z\cdot f(z)| \to 0$ for $\left|x\right| \to \infty$. We can solve sums of the form $$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^n f(n) = -\pi \cdot \sum_{k} Res\left(\ \frac{f(z)}{\sin(\pi z)};\: z_k \right).$$
I saw that $$ s_{\epsilon}(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{\sin{kx}}{k-i\epsilon} $$
Now I have $$ s_{\epsilon}(x) = -\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot Res\left( \frac{\sin{zx}}{(z-i\epsilon)\sin{\pi z}};\: i\epsilon \right) $$
The residue comes out as $$ Res\left( \frac{f(z)}{\sin{\pi z}};\: i\epsilon \right) = \frac{\sin{i\epsilon x}}{\sin{i\epsilon \pi}}$$
Taking the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ we get $Res\left( \frac{f(z)}{\sin{\pi z}};\: i\epsilon \right) = \frac{i\epsilon x}{i\epsilon \pi} = \frac{x}{\pi}$
So now we have $$ s(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} s_{\epsilon}(x) = -\frac{x}{2} $$

Hint: $\frac{\sin(xz)}{z}$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$. Treating the function as entire gives $\frac{\sin(xz)}{z}=x$ at $z=0$.

@cambridgecircus but doesn't that mean that the function doesn't have any poles? Does that mean that the function $$ \frac{\sin{zx}}{z\cdot \sin{\pi z}} $$ has no residue because the initial function has no poles? If that's the case then the sum is $0$

How are you intending to use the residue theorem here, is the other question? My hint above relates to your specific query of how to deal with the $z=0$ case. If you're trying to use the residue theorem the way I think you are, you'll need to first show that the initial sinc function is bounded of the order $|z|^{-m}$ where ${m>1}$.

@cambridgecircus I know that if I have a function $f(z)$ with poles $z_k \not\in \mathbb{Z}$ and such as $ \left|x\cdot f(x)\right| \to 0$ for $\left|x\right| \to \infty $, the series of the form $ \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^n f(n)$  is equal to  $-\pi \cdot \sum_{k} Res\left(\frac{f(z)}{\sin{\pi z}};:z_k\right)$.

... yes but on wich contour ?

@JeanMarie on a countour containing all the poles of $f(z)$

The graphical representation of the given Fourier series :

evidences that the limit to be found is $-\tfrac12x$ (under the condition that $-\pi<x<\pi$).
Otherwise said, you have to show that :
$$0=\underbrace{\tfrac12x}_{\text{res. in pole} \ 0} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac{\sin(kx)}{k}$$
Caution : As said above, this is valid for $x \in (-\pi,\pi)$.
In general, if $x \in ((2k-1)\pi,(2k+1)\pi)$, the limit $-\tfrac12x$ has to be replaced by $-\tfrac12x+k \pi$.

@Masd You are right. I am going to make this kind of comment.

I edited the initial question if you were interested
